# how to insert values into a column of a table in successive rows by fetching values from a column in a row with a same id in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my application, I use PostgreSQL database. I have two tables namely `wc_content_definition` and `simple_web_content`. The field `web_content_definition_id` is the primary key for `wc_content_definition` table and `simple_web_content_id` is the primary key for `simple_web_content`. I have added field in `simple_web_content` named `web_content_definition_id` and I want to fill this field in all the rows with the correct value from the `wc_content_definition` table. A column named `web_content_id` in the `wc_content_definition` table stores the value of `simple_web_content_id` for that row and I am trying to use that value to get the `web_content_definition_id` and insert its value in the corresponding row in the 
`simple_web_content` table. The query I am trying to use is:

```
update simple_web_content set web_content_definition_id = (select 
wcd.web_content_definition_id from  wc_content_definition wcd, 
simple_web_content swc where  simple_web_content_id = wcd.web_content_id ) 
and swc.simple_web_content_id <> 0 and wcd.web_content_id <> 0;
```

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "swc"
>   LINE 3: ... simple_web_content_id = wcd.web_content_id ) and swc.simple...
>
> Error 
>   ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "swc"
>   SQL state: 42P01
>   Character: 209

I am using the pg-admin tool to execute the queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update simple_web_content 
set web_content_definition_id =  wcd.web_content_definition_id
from  wc_content_definition wcd 
WHERE simple_web_content_id = wcd.web_content_id 
AND simple_web_content_id <> 0 and wcd.web_content_id <> 0;
```

In the query you had, the table `wc_content_definition` can't be referenced outside the sub-query.

Comment: I had tried something similar, even when I try this query, I get the following error:ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
********** Error **********

ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000

Comment: modified it to suit postgresql. please try this.